# How to convert string into Boolean flags in C# LinQ?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have declared the Boolean flags as below.

```
[Flags]
    public enum StudentStatus
    {
        True = 1,
        False = 2

    }
```

I'm getting the value through the DataValues collections in the below line and I want to assign it into the below property.

```
var student= new Student();

student.Status= StudentInfo.Data.DataValues
                .Where(m => m.FieldName.Equals("Status"))
                .Select(m => m.StatusValue).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using .Net Framework 4 you can use [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
var student= new Student();

string status = StudentInfo.Data.DataValues
                                 .Where(m => m.FieldName.Equals("Status"))
                                 .Select(m => m.StatusValue).SingleOrDefault();
StudentStatus studentStatus;
Enum.TryParse(status, out studentStatus);

student.Status = studentStatus;
```

If the parse operation fails, result contains the default value of the `StudentStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that enum is not well suited for being a `[Flags]` enum. `[Flags]` is only used if many different values can be active at one time. It should be declared as:

```
// Removed [Flags] - not appropriate here.
public enum StudentStatus
{
    True = 1,
    False = 2
}
```

In any case, you can use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to parse the string back into an enum. Like so:

```
string statusString = StudentInfo.Data.DataValues
                                 .Where(m => m.FieldName.Equals("Status"))
                                 .Select(m => m.StatusValue).SingleOrDefault();

student.Status = (StudentStatus) Enum.Parse(typeof(StudentStatus), statusString);
```

This will work for both `[Flags]` and normal enums.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. There is a method which required the flags to be set. the above example is to understand for the conversion in such scenarios. So is your code works including the Flags??